# Reordering Columns in a Power BI Matrix

Tags: powerbi, visualization, analytics, data-analysis, powerbi-desktop

I am creating a matrix in power BI, where I want to reorder the column to show the latest week data as this gets updated every week.

Currently this is the way it shows in Power BI:
[Cuurent Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D5yIx.png)

I want this to show as below, latest week 1st:
[Expected layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WbZwr.png)

How can I achieve this ?

Currently I couldn't find a way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

In order to reorder a column, you need to create a column in exiting to give order to these dates (numeric values), you can create weeknum from these dates and then sort this particular column based on the new column created.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with Date and Rank columns

[image]

Create a relationship between this new table Date column to Main table Date column

Pull this new table Date column and values from main table into matrix

Sort new table Date column by new table Rank column